# Grid : 6 x 7 Square Cells

Tags: java, android, xml, layout, grid

I'm trying to make a layout that contains a grid with 6 rows and 7 columns. I've tried many codes on stackoverflow and other websites but I can't seem the get it to work.

Each cell has to be a square ImageView. The images in the @drawable are squares already but they should not be resized into a rectangle on different screen sizes. That why I couldn't use layout_weights.

Is there any simple way to get this done? I'm quite new to these gridviews and that is probably why I didn't understand the other questions or couldn't implement them.

Anybody that has working code for a 6 x 7 grid with square cells that I can implement with some good explanation so that I understand?

Thanks a lot in advance. Hope that somebody can help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just calculate the cell length programatically:

```
public void getCellLength(Context context){
    DisplayMetrics metrics = context.getResources().getDisplayMetrics();
    int width = metrics.widthPixels;
    int height = metrics.heightPixels;
    int length = Math.min(width,height)/6;
}
```

and set the length to your image view will do